# how to use power function to values of csv files if positive?

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, sed

I have CSV files with n row and m columns I want to check every cell(except row and column header) if it is positive I want that value to be 2 ^ value. for small used excel but the number of rows exceeds 20k can't use it on my PC, any shell/python/perl script that can do?
Thanks.

eg:
file I have

```
ProbeName   US4  US45
U53   -0.01451   0.236518645
U62    0.67387  -0.922669981
U79    0.20579   0.211221866
U93   -0.72504  -0.158386611
U19   -0.25354   1.118372946
U11    0.71177  -0.209527672
```

result file

```
ProbeName   US4     US45
U53  -0.01451        1.17814625389
U62   1.59535        -0.922669981
U79   1.15331        1.15766823622
U93  -0.72504        -0.158386611
U19  -0.25354        2.17101989391
U11   1.63782        -0.209527672
```

Comment: Did you make an attempt with `shell/python/perl`, any of it or all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR>1{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i = ($i > 0 ? 2 ^ $i : $i) } 1' file

ProbeName   US4  US45
U53 -0.01451 1.17815
U62 1.59535 -0.922669981
U79 1.15332 1.15767
U93 -0.72504 -0.158386611
U19 -0.25354 2.17102
U11 1.63781 -0.209527672
```

To get formatted output:

```
awk 'NR>1{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i = ($i > 0 ? 2 ^ $i : $i) } 1' file | column -t

ProbeName  US4       US45
U53        -0.01451  1.17815
U62        1.59535   -0.922669981
U79        1.15332   1.15767
U93        -0.72504  -0.158386611
U19        -0.25354  2.17102
U11        1.63781   -0.209527672
```

**Learn awk:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: i want to do the same thing with negative values but it gives error

Comment: i tried this for negative values but it gives positive 2^value  awk 'NR>1{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i = ($i < 0 ? 2 ^ -$i : $i) } 1' testt.txt

Comment: If you want power to be computed for positive numbers only then why are you doing this for negative numbers?

Comment: Actually, I need for both  I thought negative will be similar to positive values,,

Comment: but that converts all negative values my values should remain negative

Comment: That is because in simple maths `2 ^ any-negative-number` will always be a positive number.

Comment: is it possible to use for nagative values -(2^-(negative-number))

Comment: Then try: `awk 'NR>1{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i = ($i > 0 ? 2 ^ $i : -2 ^ $i) } 1' file`

Comment: You do realise that -2^(3/2) will attempt to do square root of -8 ... good luck

Comment: Yes, I have no idea why OP is doing this maths. Original requirement was to do for positive numbers only.